# Loop through all media files in subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am currrently trying to loop through a couple of mp4 files and convert to a different format. The below works but it only converts one file and loop stops. Initially the files are in folder `videos` and as I convert i move to folder `formatted_vids`. How can i properly loop through all mp4 files?

```
FILE_PATH="/media/videos/"
 find $FILE_PATH -name "*.mp4" | while read file
         do
            filename=$(basename "$file")
            extension="${filename##*.}"
            video_file="${filename%.*}"
            dir="/media/formatted_vids/${filename%.mp4}"
            mkdir -p "$dir"
            mv "$file" "$dir"

            ffmpeg -i $dir/${filename} -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a "$dir/${filename%.mp4}-%03d.m4a";

        done
```

Initial Folder

```
|-- /media/videos/
    |   |-- xxxx-test_file-aa1
    |       |--xxxx-test_file-aa1.mp4
    |   |-- xxxx-test_file-bb2
            |--xxxx-test_file-bb2.mp4
```

Move files to Folder:

```
|-- /media/formatted_vids/
    |   |-- xxxx-test_file-aa1
    |       |--xxxx-test_file-aa1.aac
    |   |-- xxxx-test_file-bb2
            |--xxxx-test_file-bb2.aac
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
list=`find $FILE_PATH -name "*.mp4"`
for file in $list
do
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  video_file="${filename%.*}"
  dir="/media/formatted_vids/${filename%.mp4}"
  mkdir -p "$dir"
  mv "$file" "$dir"
  ffmpeg -i $dir/${filename} -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a "$dir/${filename%.mp4}-%03d.m4a";
done
```

DISCLAIMER: I assumed the body of the loop works pretty fine.

Comment: Yes this works, i see the logic. Not sure why it didnt work the other way.

Answer (score 0):

lashgar's answer will break if the filename or path contains spaces.

Try the following for a solution that includes spaces support

```sh
find $FILE_PATH -name "*.mp4" -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  video_file="${filename%.*}"
  dir="/media/formatted_vids/${filename%.mp4}"
  mkdir -p "$dir"
  mv "$file" "$dir"
  ffmpeg -i $dir/${filename} -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a "$dir/${filename%.mp4}-%03d.m4a" < /dev/null
done
```

Note that I had to add a `< /dev/null` to the end of the ffmpeg command, this is to avoid [this error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36310/313999).

Credit goes to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343753) for the while loop with space support.

I came across this question while fixing up my own media conversion script. If anyone is interested in my script for converting mkv video files with HEVC encoding to mpg files with AVC encoding, you can find it [here](https://github.com/icolwell/utility_scripts/blob/master/hevc_to_avc.bash).